# HQL query returning duplicate records

Tags: hibernate, hql

My question is about how to resolve "returning duplicate records" after an hql query. Here is an example :

```
SELECT t0 FROM table0 t0, table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE 

(((t0.a = 1 AND t0.b = 2 AND t0.c = 3) AND (t1.a = 4 AND t1.b = 5 AND t1.c = 6)) 

OR 

((t0.a = 7 AND t0.b = 8 AND t0.c = 9) AND (t1.a = 10 AND t1.b = 11 AND t1.c = 12) AND (t2.a = 13 AND t2.b = 14 AND t2.c = 15))
```

This query returns me records correctly, however some records return more than once. And i think i know the reason. "table2 t2" didnt been used in the condition before "OR" (Between "WHERE" and "OR").
How can i avoid duplicating records?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you pasted is SQL output (not HQL), the problem is that this statement doesn't JOIN the tables properly.

I would expect tables `t0`, `t1` and `t2` to have some sort of relationship among each other and the query should contain `WHERE t0.foo = t1.bar AND t1.baz=t2.bah`. As this is missing, duplicates in results are expected.